# Error code 1215 : Foreign key error : Why am I getting this?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

While trying to create a foreign key `MovieName` in table `jobinfo` I get an `error code : 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Parent Table (`contentinfo`)

```
CREATE TABLE `contentinfo` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Movie ID',
`Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`Original_Language` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`Dubbed_Language` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`InputType` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`CreationTime` date DEFAULT NULL,
`VidEncodingTemplatePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`AudEncodingTemplatePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`CCEncodingTemplatePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ContentType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`RefMovieID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'For dubbed movie only',
`NumberOfPartsInMovie` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Multilingual` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11021 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Error gets thrown when I try to make a table `jobinfo` where there exists 2 foreign keys:

```
  create table jobinfo( JobID int, ContainerID int, 
    MovieName varchar(25), FileName varchar(25), MediaType varchar(25), 
    ContentType varchar(25), ReelIndex int,
    ReelType varchar(25), ProcessingUnitID int, 
    VidEncodingTemplate varchar(255), AudEncodingTemplate varchar(255),
    CCEncodingTemplate varchar(255), StartIndex int, 
    EndIndex int, SplitIndex int, Duration int,FileSize int, Progress int,
    JStatus varchar(25), QCStatus varchar(25), 
    QCComments varchar(255), ProcessStartTime datetime, ProcessEndTime datetime,
    ProcessingStatus varchar(25), PackagingStatus varchar(30), 
    primary key(JobID), 
    foreign key (ContainerID) references contentinfo(id), 
    foreign key (MovieName) references contentinfo(Name));
```

The error gets thrown because of the statement, `foreign key (MovieName) references contentinfo(Name)` because when this statement is removed the command works fine. What is the reason I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 foreign keys to the same table as a foreign key defines the unique relationship between 2 tables. Also a foreign key must uniquely identify a row in the other table, and as such always refer to a unique field, be it either through a unique constraint or a primary key (which is implicitly a unique constraint).

In your specific case: what if you had 2 movies with IDs 64 and 684, both titled "The Running Man" but one [from 1987](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093894) and [one from 1963](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057463), your database would be inherently corrupt because of your definition.